# merge multi rows by duplicate name in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have Data Like this But it is soo Big Like 50 thousand name
and i have duplicate names and informations not completed
so i need to merge duplicate names
any Help Please ??!  :/

[Photo link](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/IawL-3Z407nx8YRYutzd-kpBh1GgiyBNh4joPzyn3Gv-P-VltH_y-E901LlUvS06Nv_rzg=w1342-h480)

Comment: i could not insert image i have message like this :
You need at least 10 reputation to post images.
so I use HTML

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's best to present your queries, sample data, etc, as text in the question rather than as links to images.

Comment: any help ???
answers please >.<

Comment: I get a 403 (no permission) error trying to view the link you posted.

Comment: I replace it good !!

Comment: I'll answer for you this time. But Stack Overflow is not simply a support bulletin board. We like to accumulate good questions and good answers. Therefore we ask that you make your questions self-contained, without links to outside images. Also, we prefer text, because Stack Overflow participants have been known to actually test their proposed solutions to questions.

Comment: `SQL server` or `MySQL` ? Please edit question.

Comment: sorry for that it's sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by my self : 
By SQL Server 2008

```
    select distinct ST2.full_name,
    substring(
        (
            Select ', '+ST1.notes  AS [text()]
            From demo.dbo.SNHR ST1
            Where ST1.full_name = ST2.full_name
            ORDER BY ST1.full_name
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 1, 1000) [notes]

From demo.dbo.SNHR ST2
order by full_name ASC
```

and thank you (Ollie Jones) you answer help me alot in mysql :)

Answer (score 0):

Fifty thousand records is quite small compared to the capabilities of **MySQL**, so don't worry about overtaxing your server.

Just to get a list of deduplicated names, you can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       `full-name`
  FROM table
 ORDER BY `full-name`
```

To try to construct a fully deduplicated table is a little more complex. There are probably some business rules involved in this process that you have not shared with us.

But you can try this aggregating query.

```
 SELECT `full-name`,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT age ORDER BY age) AS age,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT notes ORDER BY notes) AS notes
    FROM table
   GROUP BY `full-name`
```

Comment: thnx but give me error
'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.